# Formula contains a residual 1 that I cannot get rid of

Tags: excel

I've tried to debug this formula a number of times and cannot locate why the issue is happening. The formula I have in `G56`:

`=IF(G41="",MAX(0,SUM(G36,IF(G46="Satisfactory",-3,0),IF(G48="No issues identified",0,1),IF(G50="Transparent",-2,0),IF(G52="High",-5,IF(G52="Medium-High",-4,IF(G52="Medium",0,IF(G52="Low-Medium",-1,IF(G52="Low",5,IF(G52="N/A",0)))))))))`

This formula is supposed to calculate a raw score based off of a separate value already predetermined in `G36`

Right now as I look at the output if `G36` has a value of 20, the value in `G56` is 21. No values are input into `G46, G48, G50, G52` that would add the additional 1 of value.

Comment: You have a condition: `IF(G48="No issues identified",0,1)` and because G48 does not equal "No issues identified" (because as you stated there is no value input in that cell), then it resolves to the False portion which is 1.  This causes the result to be 21.

Comment: I thought about that but didnt make the connection till now, because this is the only factor where a blank contains a value. Thanks!